# How do I get the correct last modified dates in github

Tags: windows-10, git, date-modified

Is there a way to get the correct last modified times for files in my git repository in windows 10 (time displayed in git repository rather than displaying last modified right now)?

Also, can I do this when downloading files/folders in general?

Not very tech savvy so would prefer a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sh
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%cd filepath
```

This will find the most recent commit for the file and extract the date/time when it was committed. (Note that there are 2 dates associated with a Git commit: [the author date and the commit date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857467/16330198).)

Note also that this represents the date/time when the file was committed on the developer's machine, not when the file was pushed to the repository.

If you'd like the date/time in a different format, see [the documentation for `git log`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) under "PRETTY FORMATS".

Comment: Commit date is not the last modified date.

Remember that git has a wide audience. OP might not be a dev where having an accurate commit date matters, but could be a writer or designer of some sort that need the file mod dates for some internal purpose.

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere The question makes clear that they aren't looking for the date when a file was modified in their filesystem; they're looking for its date in the Git repository. If someone wants an answer to the former, this question is not the place to look for it.